# Is there any way to reduce this ado.net code?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqlparameter

I need reduce significantly this code, is there any way to create a sql parameter describing its direction? 
Here is the code:

```
    Dim Oparam1 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@ROJO", SqlDbType.Int)
    Dim Oparam2 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@AMBAR", SqlDbType.Int)
    Dim Oparam3 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@AMARILLO", SqlDbType.Int)
    Dim Oparam4 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@VERDE", SqlDbType.Int)
    Oparam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Oparam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Oparam3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Oparam4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    command.Parameters.Add(Oparam1)
    command.Parameters.Add(Oparam2)
    command.Parameters.Add(Oparam3)
    command.Parameters.Add(Oparam4)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I see 3 sets of 4 nearly identical lines of code. Create a method and pass in parameters for what can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [overload of the constructor that includes the direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a10hy4y.aspx), but then you have to specify a lot of other parameters, so the code won't be any shorter after all.

You can make an extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module SqlExtensions

  <Extension()>
  Public Function SetOutput(parameter As SqlParameter) As SqlParameter
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Return parameter
  End Function

End Module
```

Now you can use that on the parameters:

```
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ROJO", SqlDbType.Int).SetOutput())
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AMBAR", SqlDbType.Int).SetOutput())
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AMARILLO", SqlDbType.Int).SetOutput())
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@VERDE", SqlDbType.Int).SetOutput())
```

Answer (score 2):

For each parameter you could use

C#

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.Int)
    {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
```

VB.NET

```
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.Int) With { _
    .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output _
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ROJO", SqlDbType.Int) With {.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
```